# Change the selected item of a treeview in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview, selecteditem

I have a treeview with several items in it. How do I force the treeView to select a specific item ? Everytime I try to use any of the "Selected..." property, I get the error that it is read-only and cannot be set either in code or in XAML.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `Selected` property on your tree item's ViewModel, and bind to it.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20645/WPF-TreeView-Selection) is an article that explains how to do it.

Edit. Actually that uses a different way. The article I was thinking of was [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode)

Comment: I did find my problem and it wasn't that (I knew about this and though there was something missing, but it was just a reference issue). Just to mention, I use "IsSelected" in my case but I believe you could make it work with "Selected" too.